# Saving and retrieving XML and JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I'm having trouble understanding how to read and write XML and JSON data using JavaScript. Can anyone provide me detailed explanation with examples.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#b01").click(function(){
  htmlobj=$.ajax({url:"/jquery/test1.txt",async:false});
  $("#myDiv").html(htmlobj.responseText);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>this is a demo</h2></div>
<button id="b01" type="button">change</button>

</body>
</html>
```

you can use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you receive the following JSON from a web server via an API call or some form of Scraping method

```
'{ "firstName":"Foo", "lastName":"Bar" }'
```

To access this data you first need to parse the raw JSON and form a Javascript object

```
let response = JSON.parse('{ "firstName":"Foo", "lastName":"Bar" }');
```

This forms an object which we can access relativly simply

```
let firstName = response["firstName"];
let lastName = response["lastName"];
```